# Overriding DSDT with rEFInd (Enabling S3 in ACPI)

Tags: boot, acpi, refind

I have a new Dell Inspiron 5505 (AMD Ryzen 4500), and sure enough, the S3 sleep state is disabled with no BIOS option to enable it (even after a BIOS update).

After a few weeks of frustration, I learned how to (successfully) edit the DSDT and override it through GRUB. Now my laptop goes to sleep like a kitten!

However, I am at a loss of how to override the DSDT with rEFInd. Anyone know how to do this?

My GRUB configuration (works):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep"
GRUB_EARLY_INITRD_LINUX_CUSTOM="microcode.cpio acpi_override"
```

Also, in grub.cfg (works):

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-47-generic root=UUID=febd7fdb-b56d-482d-bcdf-5b6d472fa950 ro  quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep 
initrd  /boot/acpi_override /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-47-generic
```

My (attempted) rEFInd configuration (doesn't work):

```
menuentry Ubuntu {
    icon    /EFI/refind/themes/tux-refind-theme/icons/os_ubuntu.png
    volume  "Ubuntu Linux"
    loader  /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-47-generic
    initrd  /boot/acpi_override /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-47-generic
    options "ro root=UUID=febd7fdb-b56d-482d-bcdf-5b6d472fa950 quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep $vt_handoff"
}
```

- If I load through GRUB, the override works, and I can put the computer into S3 sleep.
- If I load normally through rEFInd's auto-detected entry, Linux boots, but it doesn't know to override the DSDT, and my laptop won't sleep.
- If I try loading through my manual rEFInd entry, I get this error:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.4.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu
Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 5505/0MJ6CM, BIOS 1.2.1 07/15/2020
Call Trace:
 dump_stack+0x6d/0x9a
 panic+0x101/0x2e3
 mount_block_root+0x23f/0x2e8
 mount_root+0x38/0x3a
 prepare_namespace+0x13f/0x194
 kernel_init_freeable+0x231/0x255
 ? rest_init+0xb0/0xb0
 kernel_init+0xe/0x100
 ret_from_fork+0x22/0x40
Kernel Offset: 0x1b800000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]---
```

- I tried separating the override and initrd.img lines. Linux certainly boots without errors, but completely ignores the ACPI (DSDT) override:

```
menuentry Ubuntu {
    icon    /EFI/refind/themes/tux-refind-theme/icons/os_ubuntu.png
    volume  "Ubuntu Linux"
    loader  /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-47-generic
    initrd  /boot/acpi_override
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-47-generic
    options "root=UUID=febd7fdb-b56d-482d-bcdf-5b6d472fa950 ro quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep $vt_handoff"
}
```

- Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or perhaps not doing?
- Anyone been succesful in overriding a DSDT through using rEFInd?

---

SIDENOTE:

For the curious, I removed the "If" statements surrounding the S3 state in the DSDT file, which solved the sleep problem.

From this:

```
If (LEqual (CNSB, Zero))
{
    If (LEqual (DAS3, One))
    {
        Name (_S3, Package (0x04)  // _S3_: S3 System State
        {
            0x03, 
            0x03, 
            Zero, 
            Zero
        })
    }
}
```

to this:

```
Name (_S3, Package (0x04)  // _S3_: S3 System State
{
    0x03, 
    0x03, 
    Zero, 
    Zero
})
```

Comment: Does it work if you put them on seperate lines (e.g. `initrd  /boot/acpi_override` and `initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-47-generic`)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried following your suggestion and put them on separate lines. Linux certainly boots without errors, but completely ignores the ACPI (DSDT) override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rEFInd manual boot stanzas cause many people problems -- this type of configuration was once common, back in the days of GRUB Classic and LILO, but it's basically a forgotten art today, so I see a lot of people who attempt such configurations but they fail because of typos or misunderstandings of the finicky details that they require. In the case of the example you've shown, one problem is that you can specify only one initrd file on the `initrd` line in `refind.conf`'s manual boot stanza definition. If you need to specify multiple initrd files, they must be listed on the `options` line. There may be other problems I've missed, too.

Instead, I recommend you delete the custom boot stanza configuration and instead edit `/boot/refind_linux.conf`. (If this file is not present, then you can create it with the `mkrlconf` script that comes with rEFInd. It may already be installed and on your path, depending on how you installed rEFInd. If not, you can extract it from a rEFInd `.zip` file.) You can add your additional kernel command-line parameters in this way; *however,* I'm not sure about the `/boot/acpi_override` file in your GRUB configuration. It looks like that's an additional custom initrd file, in which case you should be able to add it as an extra kernel command-line option (`initrd=/boot/acpi_override`); *however,* once you do that, you'll also need to explicitly add your standard initrd file (possibly using `%v` to identify the kernel version number). The end configuration would look something like this:

```
"Boot with ACPI override" "root=UUID=febd7fdb-b56d-482d-bcdf-5b6d472fa950 ro quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep initrd=\boot\acpi_override initrd=\boot\initrd.img-%v-generic"
```

Also, note the use of backslashes (`\`) in the path specification for the initrd files; it's the *EFI* that's used to load the initrd files, and the EFI uses backslashes, rather than Linux-style forward slashes (`/`), to separate directory elements.

Comment: The override works! Thanks for your help!